# How to set the colors in a dendrogram based on cluster?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have visualized 8 categories/clusters with a d3 dendrogram. The result can be seen in the snippet below here:

```js
const width = 1500,
      height = 600;

const cluster = d3.cluster()
  .size([width - 160, height]);

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

var theData = {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "equity",
   "children": [
     {
       "name":"vanilla equity",
       "children":[
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Aberdeen Standard"},
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Alliance Bernstein"},
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Eastspring"},
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Fidelity"},
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Invesco"},
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "UBS"},
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Fullerton"},
           {"name": "Fullerton"}
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Schroders"},
           {"name": "Schroders"}
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "APS"},
           {"name": "APS"}
         ]
         },
         {
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [
           {"name": "Value Partners"},
           {"name": "Value Partners"},
           {"name": "Value Partners"},
           {"name": "Value Partners"},
           {"name": "Value Partners"},
           {"name": "Value Partners"},
           {"name": "Value Partners"},
         ]
         }
        ]
   },
   {
    "name": "big data equity",
    "children": [
     {"name": "BlackRock"},
     {"name": "BlackRock"},
     {"name": "BlackRock"}
    ]
   }
 ]
  },


  {
   "name": "mixed",
   "children": [
     {
      "name": "mixed",
      "children": [
       {"name": "Allianz"},
      ]
    },
    {
     "name": "mixed",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Mirae"},
     ]
   },
    {
     "name": "mixed",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AZ"},
      {"name": "AZ"},
      {"name": "AZ"},
      {"name": "AZ"}
     ]
   },

   ]
 },

 {
  "name": "fixed income",
  "children": [
    {
     "name": "fixed income",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Aberdeen Standard"},
     ]
   },
   {
    "name": "fixed income",
    "children": [
     {"name": "Neuberger Berman"},
     {"name": "Neuberger Berman"},
    ]
  },
   {
    "name": "fixed income",
    "children": [
     {"name": "Schroders"},
     {"name": "Schroders"},
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "fixed income",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Fidelity"},
    {"name": "Fidelity"},
    {"name": "Fidelity"},
   ]
 },
 {
  "name": "fixed income",
  "children": [
   {"name": "UBS"},
   {"name": "UBS"},
   {"name": "UBS"},
  ]
},
  ]
},

{
 "name": "CTA",
 "children": [
   {
    "name": "CTA",
    "children": [
     {"name": "Man Investments"},
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "CTA",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Winton"},
    {"name": "Winton"},
    {"name": "Winton"},
    {"name": "Winton"},
    {"name": "Winton"},
    {"name": "Winton"},
   ]
 }

 ]
},

{
 "name": "Quant",
 "children": [
   {
    "name": "Quant",
    "children": [
     {"name": "Man Investments"},
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Quant",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DE Shaw"},
   ]
 },
  {
   "name": "Quant",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Neuberger Berman"},
    {"name": "Neuberger Berman"}
   ]
 }

 ]
},

{
 "name": "FOF",
 "children": [
   {
    "name": "FOF",
    "children": [
     {"name": "UBS"},
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "FOF",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Schroders"},
   ]
 }
 ]
},
{
 "name": "All weather",
 "children": [
   {
    "name": "All weather",
    "children": [
     {"name": "Bridgewater"},
    ]
  }
 ]
}
 ]
};

    const root = d3.hierarchy(theData);
    cluster(root);

//console.log(root.links())

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#003366","#366092","#4f81b9","#95b3d7","#b8cce4","#f6d18b","#e4a733","#a6a6a6","#d9d9d9","#ffffcc","#b29866"]);

var nodeG = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(root.links())
    .attr('class','node')
    .enter()
    .append('g');

    nodeG.append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", elbow)
      .style('stroke-width', '3px')
      .style('stroke', function(d) {return colorScale(d.source.data.children)});
/*
    nodeG.append('text')
        .attr('x',function(d) {return d.target.x})
        .attr('y',function(d) {return d.target.y})
        .text(function(d) {return d.target.data.name});
*/


function elbow(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
      + "H" + d.target.x + "V" + d.target.y;
}
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

My categories are:

- Equity (vanilla, big data)
- Mixed
- Fixed income
- CTA
- Quant
- FOF
- All weather

After navigating through the data in the console, I thought the following would color code on the major 8 splits:

```
nodeG.append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", elbow)
  .style('stroke-width', '3px')
  .style('stroke', function(d) {return colorScale(d.source.data.children)});
```

However this was not the case. In fact, I'm not sure exactly what that did, I can't understand the color logic; it seems to color code based on node count rather than name?

### Question

Is there a simple way to color code based off of major splits for clusters in a d3 dendrogram (in my case, 8)? In other words, I want all nodes from "mixed" to be one color, and all nodes from "fixed income" to be another color, and so forth. If I must tailor the color coding based on the dataset, then what is wrong with my particular color logic? I have tried slicing and dicing all sorts of ways, the above is the closest I could get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the ordinal scale's domain:

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#003366", "#366092", "#4f81b9", "#95b3d7", "#b8cce4", "#f6d18b", "#e4a733", "#a6a6a6", "#d9d9d9", "#ffffcc", "#b29866"])
    .domain(["vanilla equity", "big data equity", "mixed", "fixed income", "CTA", "Quant", "FOF", "All weather"]);
```

If you don't, the domain will be dynamically created according to the new values you pass to the scale.

Also, according to your desired domain, I'd say that you want `colorScale(d.source.data.name)`, not `colorScale(d.source.data.children)` (which by the way is an array, not a string).

Here is the code with those changes:

```js
const width = 1500,
  height = 600;

const cluster = d3.cluster()
  .size([width - 160, height]);

const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

var theData = {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [{
      "name": "equity",
      "children": [{
          "name": "vanilla equity",
          "children": [{
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                "name": "Aberdeen Standard"
              }, ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                "name": "Alliance Bernstein"
              }, ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                "name": "Eastspring"
              }, ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                "name": "Fidelity"
              }, ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                "name": "Invesco"
              }, ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                "name": "UBS"
              }, ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                  "name": "Fullerton"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Fullerton"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                  "name": "Schroders"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Schroders"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                  "name": "APS"
                },
                {
                  "name": "APS"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "name": "vanilla equity",
              "children": [{
                  "name": "Value Partners"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Value Partners"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Value Partners"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Value Partners"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Value Partners"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Value Partners"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Value Partners"
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "big data equity",
          "children": [{
              "name": "BlackRock"
            },
            {
              "name": "BlackRock"
            },
            {
              "name": "BlackRock"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },


    {
      "name": "mixed",
      "children": [{
          "name": "mixed",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Allianz"
          }, ]
        },
        {
          "name": "mixed",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Mirae"
          }, ]
        },
        {
          "name": "mixed",
          "children": [{
              "name": "AZ"
            },
            {
              "name": "AZ"
            },
            {
              "name": "AZ"
            },
            {
              "name": "AZ"
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "fixed income",
      "children": [{
          "name": "fixed income",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Aberdeen Standard"
          }, ]
        },
        {
          "name": "fixed income",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Neuberger Berman"
            },
            {
              "name": "Neuberger Berman"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "fixed income",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Schroders"
            },
            {
              "name": "Schroders"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "fixed income",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Fidelity"
            },
            {
              "name": "Fidelity"
            },
            {
              "name": "Fidelity"
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "fixed income",
          "children": [{
              "name": "UBS"
            },
            {
              "name": "UBS"
            },
            {
              "name": "UBS"
            },
          ]
        },
      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "CTA",
      "children": [{
          "name": "CTA",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Man Investments"
          }, ]
        },
        {
          "name": "CTA",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Winton"
            },
            {
              "name": "Winton"
            },
            {
              "name": "Winton"
            },
            {
              "name": "Winton"
            },
            {
              "name": "Winton"
            },
            {
              "name": "Winton"
            },
          ]
        }

      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "Quant",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Quant",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Man Investments"
          }, ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Quant",
          "children": [{
            "name": "DE Shaw"
          }, ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Quant",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Neuberger Berman"
            },
            {
              "name": "Neuberger Berman"
            }
          ]
        }

      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "FOF",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FOF",
          "children": [{
            "name": "UBS"
          }, ]
        },
        {
          "name": "FOF",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Schroders"
          }, ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "All weather",
      "children": [{
        "name": "All weather",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Bridgewater"
        }, ]
      }]
    }
  ]
};

const root = d3.hierarchy(theData);
cluster(root);

//console.log(root.links())

var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#003366", "#366092", "#4f81b9", "#95b3d7", "#b8cce4", "#f6d18b", "#e4a733", "#a6a6a6", "#d9d9d9", "#ffffcc", "#b29866"])
  .domain(["vanilla equity", "big data equity", "mixed", "fixed income", "CTA", "Quant", "FOF", "All weather"]);

var nodeG = svg.selectAll('.node')
  .data(root.links())
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .enter()
  .append('g');

nodeG.append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", elbow)
  .style('stroke-width', '3px')
  .style('stroke', function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.source.data.name)
  });
/*
    nodeG.append('text')
        .attr('x',function(d) {return d.target.x})
        .attr('y',function(d) {return d.target.y})
        .text(function(d) {return d.target.data.name});
*/


function elbow(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y +
    "H" + d.target.x + "V" + d.target.y;
}
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```